# Is is possible to limit search result to the root site and a specific subsite?

Tags: search-results

I am using the `path` token to limit the search result to a site, but that is searching the subsites as well. How can I exclude the subsites and search only the content in the root site and a specific subsite?

example: `path:https://domain.com/site/site1 OR https://domain.com/sites/site1/subweb1`

but not anything that comes underneath it, like: `https://domain.com/sites/site1/sub2 ... etc`

can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Using = instead of : should do it. 
Have a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference for more information

Comment: used it, but returns not results. No content found.

Comment: Ah i see. You are correct. Then use the first of your options and exclude the subsites in question by using ”-path:” unfortunatelly there is no easy way of doing what you are asking